# python -telegram чат bot не присылает картинку в ответном письме

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, чат

Eсли получать от бота текстовое сообщение кнопка возврат на предыдущее меню работает,как только добавляю отправку фото,кнопка становиться не активной и выпадает ошибка.

```
elif call.data == "key_typec":
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Купить", callback_data="11")
        backbutton = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="??Назад", callback_data="czy")
        keyboard.add(backbutton,key1)
         bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="выбирай раздел",reply_markup = keyboard)

        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open('c://123/file_11.jpg', 'rb'), caption="описание",
                       reply_markup = keyboard)
```

при добавление отправки фото появляется ошибка.
Что делаю не так?

```
C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/TECHNO/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bot.py
2020-07-15 21:48:28,765 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/TECHNO/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bot.py", line 110, in callback_inline
    reply_markup=keyboard)
  File "C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1090, in edit_message_text
    disable_web_page_preview, reply_markup)
  File "C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 682, in edit_message_text
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 65, in _make_request
    return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
  File "C:\Users\TECHNO\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 84, in _check_result
    raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit"}']
"
2020-07-15 21:48:28,766 (__init__.py:443 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit"}']"
```

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки

Comment: bot.edit_message_media(message.chat.id, open('C://123/file_11.jpg', 'rb'),reply_markup=keyboard)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined пробывал,сейчас такая ошибка

Comment: Пишу вот так и все равно ошибка.Я не могу просто привязать картинку в ответном сообщении...bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('C://123/file_11.jpg', 'rb'),reply_markup=keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

проверил ваш код. изменил путь к файлу и добавил `elif` - всё работает.

по нажатию кнопки `key_typec` сообщение изменяется на `выбирай раздел [Назад] [Купить]` и отправляется еще одно сообщение `photo [Назад] [Купить]`.

при нажатии `Назад` в сообщении c фото - бот отправляет `czy`, так же как и при нажатии `Назад` в текстовом сообщении.

```
def callback_inline(call):
if call.data == "key_typec":
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Купить", callback_data="11")
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data="czy")
    key.add(back, key1)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="выбирай раздел",
                          reply_markup=key)

    bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open('files/123.png', 'rb'), caption="описание",
                   reply_markup=key)
elif call.data == 'czy':
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'czy')
```

Comment: подскажите делаю многоуровневое меню,и соответственно кнопки реализованы if и большим количеством elif.правильно ли это.....в одной функции

Comment: не могу сказать правильно или нет, потому что не встречал других реализаций. но моя функция `callback_inline(call)` содержит 85 `elif` ) работает стабильно, проблем или ошибок в этой функции не наблюдал ни разу за 2 года работы бота

Comment: спасибо большое буду пробывать,пока ошибка выскакивает.  Подскажите ,пробую запустить бота 24/7 на ubuntu 20. Бот работает 10-50 минут и отваливается...что можно предпринять?

Comment: Я пробывал запускать его в фоновом потоке Screen  ,не выходит....Возможно знаете или сталкивались?

Comment: я не знаю как ту перейти в чат, чтобы не флудить в комментах. можете написать свой ник в телеграм?

Comment: а вообще, как запускаете? `polling` или `webhook`? просто запускаете скрипт, типа `python3 mybot.py` или через `service`?